# Using JDK 6 style classpath with javac ANT compile task

Tags: ant, classpath, javac, java-6

Does anybody have an example of using JDK 6 style - only defining the directory and not list of each and every jar in the directory - classpath with an ANT javac compile task?

We tried it like this

compile.classpath=c:....\WEB-INF\lib*;...websphere...\a.jar;...websphere...\b.jar;   etc. and used this classpath in the javac task, but the libraries from WEB-INF\lib were not being recognised.

So, I am wondering if it is possible to use this type of construct with ANT.  The ANT version is 1.8.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not yet know, why this works vs. why it doesn't work without these attributes, but I was able to get the wildcard part to work by using the fork="yes" and executable="path-to-my-executable" attributes in the javac task.

Answer (score 0):

Typically we use [path like structures](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) .

```
<path id="project.classpath">
   <fileset dir="${libdirectory}">
       <include name="*.jar"/>
   </fileset>
</path>
```

The the project.classpath is used in javac task. See more at [ant examples](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html)

Comment: This is how the task is defined now in the working build.  But this construct expands it to the complete list of jars in the directories. ( This make the classpath really big - about 5k characters ) With JDK 1.6, that is not necessary.  With JDJ 1.6, we should be able to just list the directories with /* instead of listing all the jars in it.